# Identity as lower bound of sine

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I'm struggling to rigorously proof

$$ \sin(2x) \geq x \qquad (0 \leq x \leq \pi/4) $$

Any ideas?

Comment: do you know calculus? if so, consider $f(x) = \sin(2x)-x$ and show that $f(x)\geq 0$ on $x \in [0, \pi/4]$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $f$ given by $f(x)=\sin (2x)-x$ for all $x$ in $[0,\pi/4]$. Differentiate it.

Answer (score 8):

Think I got it:

$$ 0 = (\sin(2x) - x)' = 2\cos(2x) - 1 $$

renders $ x_m = \pi/6 $ which is a maximum as

$$ (\sin(2x) - x)'' = -4\sin(2x) \leq 0 $$

So global minimum is attained only at the border, leaving zero at the left and on the right

$$ \sin(2\pi/4) - \pi/4 = 1 - \pi/4 > 0 $$

as $ \pi < 4 $.

Comment: Nice job.${{}}$

Comment: I don't understand part of this: so you proved that $\sin 2x > x$ on the left and right borders, but how does that prove this inequality for all $x$?

Comment: @Ovi if $f(x) = \sin(2x) - x \geq 0$ on the border, and $f$ attains it's minimum there, then $f(x) \geq 0$ also in between.

Comment: @arney Yeah thanks for some reason I got confused about what $f(x)$ was and I thought you were trying to conclude that $f(x)>x$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Note that the condition is equivalent to showing that
$\operatorname{sinc} x \ge \frac{1}{2}$ for $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

We see that $\operatorname{sinc} \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{2}{\pi} > \frac{1}{2}$, and $\operatorname{sinc}$ is decreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Hence the condition is true.